# How to disable Wifi auto-connect on boot

Tags: networking, server, 17.10

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 17.10 and while using the installer, connected to my home wireless network. I have now plugged it in via Ethernet and set up that connection with a static ip which is working properly. My problem now is that i would like to disconnect / delete the WiFi network. There is nothing for WiFi listed under `/etc/network/interfaces`, there are no conf files listed in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` or `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` (network manager didn't even seem to be installed as `nmcli` told me to install it with apt-get).

Where is my wireless network info being stored and how do I disable it?

Comment: Hint: please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*yaml`

Comment: netplan is exactly what I was looking for! I assumed there was some package that was used to create the network from the install but all my google searching for disconnecting a wifi network only led me to how to add or delete post-install. Thank you!

Comment: I'd probably remove all the ethernet settings from `/etc/network/interfaces` and add them to netplan in place of the no longer needed wireless. If you need any help, post back and I'll be happy to propose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall the usual WiFi packages?

```
apt --purge wireless-tools wpasupplicant
```

Check if they are installed, that should "purge" the problem.